# Creating a REST API with PHP: getting domainname of request host

Tags: php

So I am working on a API, and I want to check which domainname is requesting information from the API.

So, the client has a cURL script, this script sends a POST request to the server. The server needs to know the domainname of this request.

But I don't know how to check which domainname sended a POST request?

Any idea's?

Comment: Maybe [the server variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)?

Comment: @castis no, the servers needs to know which domain is sended. not the client.

Comment: no, this is not a duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`

from the docs:

```
'REMOTE_HOST'
    The Host name from which the user is viewing the current page. The reverse dns lookup is based off the REMOTE_ADDR of the user.

    Note: Your web server must be configured to create this variable. For example in Apache you'll need HostnameLookups On inside httpd.conf for it to exist. See also gethostbyaddr().
```

Comment: Undefined index: REMOTE_HOST

Comment: @DazDylz yes read the documentation that I attached `Note: Your web server must be configured to create this variable.`